# Enquire.js: Don't get the purpose of "setup" handler

Tags: media-queries, viewport, enquire.js

I don't quite get the idea behind enquire.js' "setup" handler.

**Case:**

I want to load content through ajax once when you're not in a small viewport (lt 600px).

Naturally I would do `enquire.register('(min-width: 600px)', { setup: myFunction });`.

**Problem:**

Now I tested this multiple times but the setup handler also gets fired when you're in a small screen, which totally eliminates the benefit of the setup handler imo, because you would want to only load the ajax content once you enter a viewport bigger than 600px, wouldn't you?

See [example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5uaCx/).

**Conclusion:**

So actually I wouldn't even need the setup handler because I simply could load the content outside the enquire register and would have the same effect. (Which of course isn't what I want...)

Can someone tell me if I just misunderstood the purpose of setup or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine with the `deferSetup` flag to defer the setup callback until the first match. This example illustrates the feature:

```
enquire.register(someMediaQuery, {
  setup : function() {
    console.log("setup");
  },
  deferSetup : true,

  match : function() {
    console.log("match");
  },

  unmatch : function() {
    console.log("unmatch");
  }
});
```

You can see a working example here: http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/examples/defer-setup/

Comment: I wrote TFM so it's a little easier for me to remember the details ;-)